# Jmeter error trying to record a sample java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed marshalling

Tags: java, jmeter

I have one Linux VPS dedicated just for running a jmeter. The tests run fine, but failed requests are not written to error.jtl with SimpleDataWriter. Java error is written to jmeter.log instead.

I run the tests in non-gui mode:

```
jmeter -n -t om5.jmx -j results-tmp1/t3-l1-jmeter.log
```

**The error**

```
2016/07/08 16:59:35 ERROR - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector:
Error trying to record a sample java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed marshalling:class:class
org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult,content:org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult@1f605bfa[saveConfig=org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration@b4a9237e,parent=<null>,
responseData={},responseCode=500,label=03 add to cart,resultFileName=,samplerData=<null>,threadName=Thread Group 1-149,responseMessage=Number of samples in transaction : 2, number of failing samples : 1,
responseHeaders=,contentType=,requestHeaders=,timeStamp=1467989884109,startTime=1467989884109,endTime=1467989975286,idleTime=1001,pauseTime=0,assertionResults=<null>,subResults=[reset basketItems, /some-page],
dataType=,success=false,files=[res-tmp/t400-l5-errors.jtl],dataEncoding=<null>,elapsedTime=90176,latency=0,connectTime=0,startNextThreadLoop=false,stopThread=false,stopTest=false,
stopTestNow=false,isMonitor=false,sampleCount=1,bytes=806,headersSize=192,bodySize=614,groupThreads=400,allThreads=400,nanoTimeOffset=1467988012523,useNanoTime=true,nanoThreadSleep=5000,location=<null>]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.saveSampleResult(SaveService.java:345)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sampleOccurred(ResultCollector.java:557)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:819)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doEndTransactionSampler(JMeterThread.java:534)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.triggerEndOfLoopOnParentControllers(JMeterThread.java:342)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I cannot find what is wrong. It is only that one machine, that gives me this error. Everywhere else I try it, it works correctly.

The OS is Debian Jessie (8.5) - minimal from official repositories. I tried many different versions of java (1.7, 1.8) - currently running on the latest 1.8 (`1.8.0_92-b14`) and I have the latest apache-jmeter `3.0 r1743807`, but previously I used `2.13 r1665067`. I don't use any third-party plugins.

I didn't notice exactly when it stopped working, what change was done (some os update, maybe some change in jmx), but I have my tests in git, so I checked out older version from the date of my last full error.jtl and it is not writing the errors to jtl as well.

I reinstalled the Debian to Ubuntu 16.04 and nothing changed.

I don't know how to debug that problem, what should I do, because on any other machine I have an access to, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've fixed this problem until now?
I had the same issue, and I fixed it just now.
I guess in your jmeter script, you checked the hostname to record sample result, in jmeter.log, you could find such message: jmeter couldn't get the linux Local IP, so hostname is Null, exception threw out.

So what you need to do is remove 'Save Hostname' from 'Sample Result Save Configuration' tab.